# Worst case input of linked list algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

Algorithm:

> A postings list is a singly linked list with an additional jump field at each node. The jump field points to any other node. The jump-list ordering is where we always first follow the jump field if it leads to a node that has not been explored previously, and then search from the node at the `next position. Write a recursive routine that takes the postings list and compute the jump-first order.

Here's the author solution (pretty straightforward):

```
def search_postings_list(L):
  def search_postings_list_helper(L):
    if L and L.order == -1:
      L.order = order[0]
      order[0] += 1
      search_postings_list_helper(L.jump)
      search_postings_list_helper(L.next)
  order = [0]
  search_postings_list_helper(L)
```

My Question:

According to the solution, the worst case input is where every node's jump node and next node are equal. I'm not sure whether I'm right or wrong.

If that's the case, the stack size does indeed get N max and each node is touched twice, but ... each node is touched twice even if that isn't the case. For example, if `node A` had a jump pointer to `node C` and its `next` pointer to `node B`, then `node C` would be explored before `node B` but eventually, `node B` would put `node C` back onto the recursive stack (it would just be popped off after the 3rd line). So why is this the worst case scenario?

Comment: Do you mean worst case in terms of time or space or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be quoting from the book [Elements of Programming Interviews: The Insiders' Guide](https://books.google.be/books?id=y6FLBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=%22A+postings+list+is+a+singly+linked+list+with+an+additional+jump+field+at+each+node.%22&source=bl&ots=AtJtcLu3zg&sig=vxzBY_yxozzGQiiWU_6cRzQ8kAo&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibidXtlJrbAhWGyKQKHfwdBYAQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22A%20postings%20list%20is%20a%20singly%20linked%20list%20with%20an%20additional%20jump%20field%20at%20each%20node.%22&f=false), section 9.5.

It correctly states that the time complexity of this algorithm is *O(n)*. When it speaks of a worst case it is about the space complexity, not the time complexity (for which there is no particular worst case as you correctly reasoned):

> The recursive implementation has maximum call stack depth of *n*, ... A worst case input is one where every node's jump and next node are equal.

Note the context of this quote: this is a worst case for the stack size (space).

Comment: If every node's jump is the previous node, with the first going to the last, doesn't that also create a stack depth of `n`?

Comment: Yes, but the book only mentions one example ("a worst case", not "the worst case").